# How to Format cells that change every week

Tags: vba

I have a code that searches my spreadsheet for an "x" in column L, and if it does, it copies the entire row and pastes it into a new sheet. This continues until there are no more "x" in the column.

What I want to do is have the macro also put the "All Border" border in these cells. The problem I am running into is that one week the new tab will have 3 rows of data and another week it could have 23.

How can I make it so that it only formats the cells that have data. (In my case, it will always be columns B:L that I need formatted, but the rows will vary).

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code you have in the Original Post using edit, and explain what you have tried.

Comment: I don't have any code that relates to what I am trying to do. I am very new to coding, so I don't really know where to begin with this situation, and have been researching on how to do it for hours.

Answer (score 0):

check the below code, especially if .usedrange property works for you.

```
sub formatBorder()

dim rng as range
dim wks as worksheet

set wks = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1") 'change sheet name if required
set rng = intersect(wks.usedrange,wks.range("B:L")) 

if rng is nothing then goto terminate

With rng.Borders
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous  
  .Color = vbRed
  .Weight = xlThin
End With

terminate:
set wks = nothing
set rng = nothing

end sub
```